# Paginating Distinct Values in Mongo

Tags: performance, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to retrieve district values for a field from a collection in my database. The `distinct` command is the obvious solution. The problem is that some fields have a large number of possible values and are not simple primitive values (i.e. are complex sub-documents instead of just a string). This means the results are large causing it to overload the client I am delivering the results to.

The obvious solution is to paginate the resulting distinct values. But I cannot find a good way to optimally do this. Since `distinct` doesn't have pagination options (limit, skip, etc) I am turning to the aggregation framework. My basic pipeline is:

```
[
  {$match: {... the documents I am interested in ...}},
  {$group: {_id: '$myfield'},
  {$sort: {_id: 1},
  {$limit: 10},
]
```

This gives me the first 10 unique values for `myfield`. To get the next page a $skip operator is added to the pipeline. So:

```
[
  {$match: {... the documents I am interested in ...}},
  {$group: {_id: '$myfield'},
  {$sort: {_id: 1},
  {$skip: 10},
  {$limit: 10},
]
```

But sometimes the field I am collecting unique values from is an array. This means I have to unwind it before grouping. So:

```
[
  {$match: {... the documents I am interested in ...}},
  {$unwind: '$myfield'}
  {$group: {_id: '$myfield'},
  {$sort: {_id: 1},
  {$skip: 10},
  {$limit: 10},
]
```

Other times the field I am getting unique values for may not be an array but it's parent node might be an array. So:

```
[
  {$match: {... the documents I am interested in ...}},
  {$unwind: '$list'}
  {$group: {_id: '$list.myfield'},
  {$sort: {_id: 1},
  {$skip: 10},
  {$limit: 10},
]
```

Finally sometimes I also need to filter on data inside the field I am getting distinct values. This means I sometimes need another match operator after the unwind:

```
[
  {$match: {... the documents I am interested in ...}},
  {$unwind: '$list'}
  {$match: {... filter within list.myfield ...}},
  {$group: {_id: '$list.myfield'},
  {$sort: {_id: 1},
  {$skip: 10},
  {$limit: 10},
]
```

The above are all simplifications of my actual data. Here is a real pipeline from the application:

```
[
  {"$match": {
    "source_name":"fmls",
    "data.surroundings.school.nearby.district.id": 1300120,
    "compiled_at":{"$exists":true},
    "data.status.current":{"$ne":"Sold"}
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$data.surroundings.school.nearby"},
  {"$match": { 
    "source_name":"fmls",
    "data.surroundings.school.nearby.district.id":1300120,
    "compiled_at":{"$exists":true},
    "data.status.current":{"$ne":"Sold"}
  }},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$data.surroundings.school.nearby"}},
  {"$sort":{"_id":1}},
  {"$skip":10},
  {"$limit":10}
]
```

I hand the same `$match` document to both the initial filter and the filter after the unwind because the `$match` document is somewhat opaque from a 3rd party so I don't really know which parts of the query are filtering outside my unwind vs inside the data I am getting distinct values for.

Is there any obvious different way to go about this. In general, my strategy is working but there are some queries where it is taking 10-15 seconds to return the results. There are about 200,000 documents in the collection although only about 60,000 after the first `$match` in the pipeline is applied (which can use indexes).

Comment: Is the skip(10) a constant value or does that change for the queries that you see issue with? Also what version of MongoDB are you using? What are the indexes on the mentioned collection?

Comment: {$skip: 10} will change depending on what page I am on. Latest or almost latest version of Mongo. I have indexes that $match can take advantage of but after that I don't believe Mongo will use the indexes.

Comment: @EricAnderson Hi, did you find any solution to this after 5 years? I am facing the same problem on Sping mongo templates :D

Comment: Sorry, this was for an old project I am no longer working on and don't remember what I ended up doing.